# Where do I find information about qui and geomancy?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun

I can't seem to find much information about qui or geomancy in my *Shadowrun 4* books. What books from this edition or other editions include have more information on these topics?

Comment: Have you checked street magic yet?

Comment: habve to admit I HAD taken a look but seemingly have overread it oO

Comment: I ask simply because there **is** more information on older books (previous editions) if you already know what is shown on street magic.

Comment: ah which older books are those? (I'm intereted in as much info as I can get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both can be found on the **Street Magic**.

- Geomancy, a metamagic technique, page 56.
- *Qi*, with the *Wuxing* tradition, page 43.

There is a little more flavor information about Geomancy, [mana lines](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Manalines_and_Power_Sites) and the Wuxing Skytowers on the **Parageology** book.